# log4j log file not rolling while setting filepath on runtime

Tags: java, spring-mvc, reflection, log4j

**Code 2** is injecting Logger instance into LOG field in **Code 1**. The logs are going to the correct file but the logs are not rolling. However, when using **Code 1** with **Code 3**, logs are rolling. What I need is for **Code 1** to work with **Code 2**. The core logic for appending the RollingFileAppender is the same but I am out of ideas why the log won't roll in the first case. Will you please explain what I am doing wrong and what could be a possible solution.

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(FIELD)
@Documented
public @interface Log {
    Class<?> clazz();
}
```

**Code 1:-**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/util/")
public class UtilityController {
    @Log(clazz = COScheduler.class)
    private static Logger LOG;
}
```

**Code 2:-**

```
package text.worker.config.log;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;
import org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.ClassUtils;
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;    

@Component
public class LogInjector implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, String name) throws BeansException {
        ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(bean.getClass(), new ReflectionUtils.FieldCallback() {
            public void doWith(Field field) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
                // make the field accessible if defined private
                ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
                if (field.getAnnotation(Log.class) != null) {
                    Class<?> cl = ClassUtils.getUserClass(field.getAnnotation(Log.class).clazz());

                    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(cl);

                    if(log.getAppender("worker") == null) {
                        PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
                        patternLayout.setConversionPattern("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n");
                        try {
                            RollingFileAppender appender = new RollingFileAppender(patternLayout, "D://aa.log",true);
                            appender.setMaxFileSize("500KB");
                            appender.setMaxBackupIndex(10);
                            appender.setName("worker");
                            appender.activateOptions();
                            log.addAppender(appender);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                        }
                    }   
                    //log.warn("LogInjector postProcessBeforeInitialization Log getAppender "+field.getAnnotation(Log.class).clazz());                    

                    field.set(bean, log);
                }
            }
        });
        return bean;
    }
}
```

**Code 3:-**

```
if(LOG.getAppender("worker") == null) {
            PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
            patternLayout.setConversionPattern("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n");
            try {
                RollingFileAppender appender = new RollingFileAppender(patternLayout, "D://aa.log",true);
                appender.setMaxFileSize("500KB");
                appender.setMaxBackupIndex(10);             
                appender.setName("worker");
                appender.activateOptions();
                LOG.addAppender(appender);              
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
```